# How do I insert a new element in an array?

Tags: ruby, arrays

Suppose I have an array:

```
list = [1,2]
```

and I want to insert a new element between the other elements, for example `3`, so that the resultant output array is:

```
list = [1,3,2]
```

How do I insert a new element in an array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`insert`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-insert) method:

```
list.insert(1, 3)
#=> [1,3,2]
```

This will insert `3` into your array at index `1`.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to add the element to the back of the array you can use `<<`:

```
list << 3
```

Otherwise use `insert`:

```
list.insert(1,3)
```

Comment: +1, `<<` is the equivalent of `push`, I would have used this way, it's more ruby.

Answer (score 2):

This is a solution using the ability to assign multiple values with only one `=` call:

```
a = [1, 2]
a[1], a[2] = 3, a[1]
puts a.inspect        # displays [1, 3, 2]
```

Comment: This is called parallel assignment. It's also obfusticating what is happening.

Comment: @theTinMan Yes indeed, I was not even sure it would work before trying it. But I think it is worth mentioning anyways, Ruby is sure a great language.

Comment: Well, yeah, it'll work, but that's not always a good reason to use a particular form. :-) I love to torment the interpreter to see what sorts of odd ways I can come up with making something work, because occasionally it turns out to be better. I weigh them against maintainability and readability because those live with the code a lot longer than the coolness/oddity of it. In your answer, I'd recommend removing the IRB prompts, which will make your code stand out a lot better. It is a good way of going about it speed-wise so +1 for that. It won't work for larger arrays though.

Comment: @theTinMan totally agreed